# Empty query params in router link will be ignored correct? Angular Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

i have the following variables:

```
 inputCity;
 inputGuestNumber;
 inputCapacitySelected;
 inputCuisineSelected;
 inputPrivacySelected;
 inputVenueTypeSelected;
 inputAmenitiesSelected;
 inputNeighborhoodSelected;
```

these values may or may not be defined depending on what the user enters into a form.

I have a `router.navigate` function that has a query param set. What happens to the query params if the variable they are pointing to is undefined or otherwise empty?

```
onSubmit(){
    this.router.navigate(['/venue-list', this.inputCity], {
        queryParams:{
           guestCount: this.inputGuestNumber,
           countOption: this.inputCapacitySelected,
           cuisineSelected:this.inputCuisineSelected, 
           privacySelected:this.inputPrivacySelected,
           venueTypeSelected: this.inputVenueTypeSelected,
           amenitiesSelected: this.inputAmenitiesSelected,
           neighborhoodSelected: this.inputNeighborhoodSelected
        }
  });
```

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

queryParams are optional params which are not required to determining route to a component. But if you pass queryParams like above and some of your variable are undefined then it will request a route like this

```
localhost:3000/venue-list/:inputCity?guestCount=2&countOption=undefined&cuisineSelected=anyvalue&privacySelected=undefined
```

empty query params will not be ignored.
so now when it open venue-list component

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route
      .queryParams
      .subscribe(params => {
        this.guestcount = +params['guestCount'];
        this.countoption = +params['countOption'];<- in this.countoption you will get undefined
      });
  }
```

It will be better if you set some default value to all you query params incase some of them is undefined like this

```
subscribe(params => {
    // Defaults to 0 if no query param provided.
    this.guestcount = +params['guestCount'] || 0;
    this.countoption = +params['countOption'] || default_value;
  });
```

or use if condition to detect undefined